# What does "Bucket" mean in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, hashmap

I'm reading the book "*Learn Python the Hard way*" by Zed Shaw, and currently I'm learning about dictionaries.

In one of the exercises he creates a hashmap.py module.

```
def new(num_buckets=256):
    """Intializes a Map with a given number of buckets"""
    aMap = []
    for i in range(0, num_buckets):
        aMap.append([])
    return aMap
```

This is the first function he creates. I still have no idea what he is doing i lost track a while ago, (He claims if you just keep copying and try to understand the code it will eventually start to make sense) so now i am trying to dissect the code by googling and looking at forums. Anyways what the heck is a *bucket*? Is it some kind of programmer gibberish or does it have a meaning? The name appears in almost every function that he creates.

Here is another function he creates with bucket in it.

```
def get_bucket(aMap,key):
    bucket_id = hash_key(aMap,key)
    return aMap[bucket_id]
```

I searched stack-overflow and the web and couldn't fine a definite answer on what a *bucket* is...
I'm still a beginner almost intermediate programmer so please take note of that.

Thanks in advance.
- Allen

Comment: you can treat bucket as element of array . as cell , as space where something can live. in case of hashmap - it stores objects as key,value pairs , look at this key,value pair as a single entity - this entity lives in bucket (hash map is just an array where each cell is called bucket as complex object can live there. and key is used to calculate index of bucket where to put your element). I am not a python dev but I guess that hash map principles are the same everywhere

Comment: A hashmap is a useful data structure, and it uses buckets to hold data. But IMHO using it in introductory code is a **BAD** idea. That example is one reason why the SO Python chat room does **not** recommend _Learn Python the Hard way_. Please take a look at   [What tutorial should I read?](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F); you may also like to look at the linked article [LPTHW Complaints](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints), although much of that list will only make sense when your Python & programming skills are more advanced.

Comment: A bucket is a container for objects (just like a regular, physical bucket). See also [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144983/what-does-bucket-mean)

Comment: @PM2Ring Haha thank you for the warning on LPTHW. Good thing i haven't read too much of the book. On LPTHW Complaints i found this: *#15 After teaching methods in 38, Ex 39 teaches dictionaries and… how to build a hash table class?!* This is the example that i am talking about in this thread. Thanks for the heads up. - Allen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a hash, you store your data in key-value pairs.

Each key can be added dynamically and must be stored internally in some kind of table. But since the number of such entries is limited, multiple keys can map to a single entry.

So, you will have to store more than one value for a single table entry in a 'bucket' which could be an array, linked list, etc. and so can hold multiple key-value pairs for a single hash table entry.