# Have a list of the letters in the alphabet. Want to make buckets for each letter that will contain items

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
index_display = [letter for letter in ascii_lowercase]
```

Here the list is created and stored in the variable index_display.

I am now trying to go through this list and create a bucket for each letter. These buckets will then contain lists of items.

So far what I have is

```
buckets = dict(enumerate(index_display))
```

I actually have that enumerate in a for loop. The for loop goes through a list of partners which have a key='state'. I then want to take the letter of the state value in order to group each partner into a bucket for the given letter. Basically to organize partners alphabetically.

Here is the for loop which I would like to have include each partner in the respective bucket depending on which is the first letter of their state keys value.

```
 for partner in partners_by_state:
```

I have tuples for the partners here is example:

```
Partner(state="Texas", name="beautiful", logo="beautiful.png", 
link="http:hi.com"),
```

I have a state list as well.

```
   states = {'alabama': '',
              'arizona': '',
              'california': '',

          },
```

As well as this code

```
partners_by_state = {}
    for partner in partner_list:
        raw_state_state_name = partner.state
        state_key = raw_state_state_name.lower()
        found_value = partners_by_state.get(state_key)
        if not found_value:
            partners_by_state[state_key] = []
        partners_by_state[state_key].append(partner)

    for state, parts in partners_by_state.items():
        new_parts = sorted(parts, key=lambda x: x.name)
        partners_by_state[state] = new_parts
```

I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: what is a bucket?

Comment: There is no need to put the letters in a list, and anyway, you can just do `index_display = list(ascii_lowercase)`, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: In other words, what actual output are you expecting?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Or just use ascii_lowercase. That's what it's there for in the first place...

Comment: Well I actually have that enumerate in a for loop.

The for loop goes through a list of partners which have a key='state'. I then want to take the letter of the state value in order to group each partner into a bucket for the given letter. Basically to organize partners alphabetically.

Comment: @J.Doethe31st you need to provide, explicitly, what you want , **in the question itself**. It probably is just easiest to provide your desired output.

Comment: @MadPhysicist sure, that's why I emphasized that it wasn't necessary, twice :) just the list-comprehension was *particularly* unecessary :)

Comment: @J.Doethe31st What for loop? Please explain clearly what you mean. Show your loop code and show a sample input with expected output.

Comment: @kstullich Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576318/what-does-bucket-mean-in-python) for what a "bucket" is...

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New answer for updated question**

Use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

partners_by_state = defaultdict(list)
```

Now you can append without the if statement:

```
for partner in partner_list:
       raw_state_state_name = partner.state
       state_key = raw_state_state_name.lower()[0] # first letter
       partners_by_state[state_key].append(partner)
```

**Old answer for first part of the question**

You probably want a dictionary with list as values:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

buckets = {letter: [] for letter in ascii_lowercase}
```